# SpriteKit isUserInteractionEnabled=false Blocks Touches

Tags: sprite-kit, xcode9, isuserinteractionenabled

I am building a SpriteKit game.  The game scene is the parent of a transparent layer above it whose role is to display occasional messages to the player.  I want this layer to be transparent and inert most of the time, and of course, never receive touches.  As such, I have isUserInteractionEnabled set to false.  However, when I add this later to the scene, it blocks all touches below it.  What gives?

Edit: the parent of the MessageLayer is the game scene, and the game scene also has isUserInteractionEnabled = false, so I do not believe that the MessageLayer is inheriting the behavior.

Here is my code:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class MessageLayer: SKSpriteNode {

    init() {

        let size = CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
        super.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.blue, size: size)
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        self.name = "MessageLayer"
        alpha = 0.6
        zPosition = +200
    }

    override init(texture: SKTexture!, color: UIColor, size: CGSize)
    {
        super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.clear, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
    }

    // MARK: - Functions

    func alphaUp() {
        alpha = 0.6
    }

    func alphaDown() {
        alpha = 0.0
    }

}
```

Comment: if your game scene is also set to false, what do you expect is receiving touches?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon the scene can be set to false and the other objects still receive touch. They are handled at the view layer.

Comment: @Fluidity only if they are custom classed,  that is why I asked my question

Comment: @Knight0fDragon oh ok.. i thought u knew lol

Comment: i misread your comment my bad

Answer (score 0):

Just relay the touches to the scene / other nodes you want to do stuff with.

```
class TransparentNode: SKSpriteNode {

  init(color: SKColor = .clear, size: CGSize) {
    super.init(texture: nil, color: color, size: size)
    isUserInteractionEnabled = true
  }

  // touches began on ios:
  override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    // relay event to scene:
    scene!.mouseDown(with: event)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError() }
}


class GameScene: SKScene {

  lazy var transparentNode: SKSpriteNode = MyNode(size: self.size)

  // touches began on ios:
  override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    print("ho")
  }

  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    addChild(transparentNode)
    isUserInteractionEnabled = false
  }
}
```

And here you can see that the invisible node is sending events properly:

[image]

Comment: You are mixing macOS and iOS here

Comment: @Knight0fDragon only the comment about touchesBegan :P it works the same

Comment: the OP has probably never touched macOS code, may be confusing to them